# Guidewire Gosu blocks

Tags: guidewire, gosu

Can someone explain why does when calling function test() and passing block to it, code understands that parameter of that block is type of Account, but when calling the same block test1() and passing another block to it the code won`t compile and it considers parameter of the block as block.[case1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dx7e.png) It will only work when setting parameter type.[case2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgJS5.png)

I`m working with Policy Center v10, GW studio 5.0.4

```
var account = Account.finder.findAccountByAccountNumber("2251253246")

public function test(bl: block(Account): String) {
  print(bl(account))
}

var test1: block(block(Account): String) = \ bl: block(Account): String -> {
  print(bl(account))
}

test(\a-> a.AccountNumber)
test1(\a -> a.AccountNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very simple but deceiving at the same time.

The correct execution in your case would be as follows:

```
test(\a-> a.AccountNumber)
test1(\a : Account -> a.AccountNumber)
```

Your test() method accepts a block of param Account and return type of String.
Your test1 block actually accepts as a parameter another block (of param Account and return type of String).
Neither the method nor the outer block test1 returns anything.

So in the method test you aren't binding the block execution to a variable until inside the method. While in my example of how to execute the other block test1 I'm binding the account variable to the other block at the point of it's definition. Subtle but difference.

Having said that I'm not sure what problem you are really trying to solve here or what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Still dont get it. Test1 will work even if i do sth like var bl = \a-> a.AccountNumber and then test1(bl), but it does not work when i pass this same block directly to test1. I'm trying to achieve nice and clean code but this thing make me to specify type each time i call this test1. I dont get it, is it a bug ? My coworker tried same code on v8 gwpc and it works

Comment: have a look at my corrected answer from before - this now works for both of the executions ... still not sure what you are trying to achieve there but perhaps you will be able to apply the above to your need

Comment: Would be good if somebody from @Guidewire would comment on the different behaviour of block params matching when used in methods vs when used in blocks. The reason why it might have been working in v8 is that there were few changes in GOSU language and definitions hence it might be a bit more stricter when compiling the code and require to define the type but I haven't checked this

Comment: I can't speak to the Gosu internals, but there were significant changes to the internal implementation of Gosu between v8 and v9.  I expect the issue you're hitting is the removal of support for implicit coercions as documented here:

https://docs.guidewire.com/portal/secure/doc/pc/PolicyCenter_9.0.0/doc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=New%20and%20Changed%20Guide/f-gosu.09.18.html